# Why Lapis does not work?

Tags: centos, software-installation, lua

I have installed Lapis framework using command:

```
luarocks install lapis --local
```

It gave me success installation:

```
Updating manifest for /home/Oman/.luarocks/lib/luarocks/rocks
lapis 1.5.0-2 is now built and installed in /home/Oman/.luarocks (license: MIT)
```

After I try to create a new project:

```
[Oman@Oman ~]$ lapis new
```

And get error:

```
-bash: lapis: command not found
```

Why do I get this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not at all familiar with the `luarocks` installer (from EPEL, I hope), but I suspect that it installed an executable called `lapis` somewhere in `/home/Oman/.luarocks`, as the output says.  Maybe in `/home/Oman/.luarocks/bin`?  If you want to have it work without the full path, you'll have to add the directory with the executable to your `$PATH` variable in your shell's rc file (such as ~/.bash_profile).